# Can not type backslah \ in Gitbash

Tags: git-bash

I need to type a backslash \ in GitBash, since I'm working on a laptop I have to use Alt + 092 to type a backslash, however, when I press Alt + 092 the backslash doesn't appear in the input prompt, I tried to copy and press Ctrl + V and it doesn't work. How to type a backslash in GitBash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From several attempts I have found my error, it is clear that Alt + 092 is \, however, when typing this ASCII on Bash it has to be Alt + 92. Maybe this could be useful for anybody learning Bash from scratch.